# Provided address undefined is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

When I use

```
 web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]), "ether").toNumber()
```

it should get the balance of accounts[0] which is the coinbase

but what I get is

> "Provided address undefined is invalid, the capitalization checksum
> test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be
> converted."

Is there any way I can figure this out?

Truffle v5.4.13

Solidity v0.5.16

Web3.js v1.5.3

these are the version im using

Answer (score 0):

This means that `web3.eth.accounts[0]` is undefined. You can use

```
console.log(web3.eth.accounts)
```

to check those or if you're feeling adventurous you can learn how to use the debugger to inspect things.